# Best way to determine an "empty" image/slide

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm dealing with lots of image files - particularly with tissue samples. Often when you magnify the image and divide the image into tiles there are "blank" tiles. I need to identify these "blank" tiles and remove them. Unfortunately, these are not all one homogenous color, but you can see in my examples, I have one real tile (the obvious one) and the other three are "blank" (in quotes here because to the visual eye they are empty, but from a pixel perspective it's not a uniform value).  What's the best way in Python (using Pillow?) to determine that these 3 are blank?

[image: Normal]
[image: Gray3]
[image: Gray2]

[image: Gray1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maybe try something with numpy (or check the standard déviation or count the number of unique values)

Standard déviation of empty img should be close to zero:
(to adapt)

```
 import numpy as np
 image = Image.open('img.jpeg').convert('LA')
 # convert image to numpy array
 data = asarray(image)
 np.reshape(data, (-1,1))
 std_dev=np.std(data)
 if std_dev<1:
     check img
```

With unique count: (to adapt)

```
 image = Image.open('img.jpeg').convert('LA')
 # convert image to numpy array
 data = asarray(image)
 np.reshape(data, (-1,1)) 
 u, count_unique = np.unique(data, unique_counts =True)
 if count_unique.size< 10:
     check img
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me try that with my sample files.

Comment: Sûre it was just to give you ideas

Comment: I double checked, you probably will have to convert images in Grey scales: Image.open('image.png').convert('LA')